# How to make a JSR-168 portlet with a chart?

Tags: java, charts, portlet, jsr168

I'm trying to make a JSR-168 portlet with a chart. 
Studying about it i can run some portlets in NetBeans with portlet-container but i have to make some charts to run too.
Can some one help with a LINK or an Example?
I found that to help me:

-> dojocampus.org
-> dojotoolkit.org
-> extjs.com

I make a chart, but when i put on portlet-container have the error: "Deployment Failed Portlet war file. Possible reason can be error reading WEB-INF/portlet.xml from portlet war file". Only the portlet or the chart they work, but toghetter make the error.
JSR can run any chart type(flash, Java Script, etc)?

Att

Comment: What means "i have to make some charts to run too"? Does the portlet webapp also contains a web.xml with a servlet createing charts? How your portlet.xml and web.xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest(even not perfect) way is to create a ordinary servlet which receives the values as input parameters and output would be the picture.

Here is some basic info how to create dynamic image in servlet: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html

To generate image of graph you can use this library: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html